# OpenTok is saying Safari 13 ScreenSharing is supported

Tags: opentok, tokbox

The tokbox code for checking screensharing support is

```
OT.checkScreenSharingCapability(function (response) {
    console.log('checkScreenSharingCapability response = ', response);

    if (!response.supported || response.extensionRegistered === false) {

        // This browser does not support screen sharing
        console.log('screen share not supported');
    }
});
```

The output in Safari 13 I get is

```
checkScreenSharingCapability response =  
extensionInstalled: undefined
extensionRegistered: undefined
extensionRequired: undefined
supported: true
supportedSources: {screen: true, application: false, window: true, browser: false}
```

Therefore, it says it's supported, and does not work (the documentation says it's not supported).  This is the same response that Chrome (supported) returns, so the resposne itself seems wrong using **opentok/client 2.16.3**